# Is it possible to infer function parameter types using Compiler API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm using the Compiler API to search for structures like promises, generators, and callbacks written in JavaScript. I've decided to use TypeScript instead of other parses because of its type-checking features. After reading the [TS documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#unspecified-type-parameters-default-to-any), it seems to me that the only way to infer types from parameters **that are functions** is when the code has JSDOC (in this context I'm only aware of non-native functions), right? What would you suggest in my case? Is there any other option? Should I search for these structures considering only syntax kinds (e.g. looking for CallExpressions node children names with the same parameter names)?

This is a small example from what I want to detect:

```
const run = (fn, ...params) => (message) => `${message}: ${fn(...params)}`;
```

In this case above, I want to detect whether "fn" is a function or not. When I call for `typeChecker.typeToString(typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node))` the result is always "any".

Comment: Yes, you're right. TypeScript doesn't infer parameter types based on their usage so out of the box it wouldn't be that useful. The only option I can think of is what you suggested about implementing this yourself... which will be a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for replying, @DavidSherret. I'll see what I can do considering this :|